# Change Element on Html Return Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

For Example : I have html like this

```
<div class="time_wrapper">
  <input type="text" value="3:00 PM" id="time"/>
</div>
<button id="add">Add More</button>
```

on javascript:

```
$(document).on("click", "#add", function(){
    var clone = $("#time_wrapper").html();       
    // Do something to change clone value
      $(".time_wrapper").append(clone);
});
```

What I want to do is to change value of clone element to 4:00 PM without effect to original value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$("#add").click( function(){
    var clone = $("#time").clone();       
    // below you can read actual value and increment
    $(clone).val('4:00 PM');
      $(".time_wrapper").append(clone);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).on("click", "#add", function(){
    var clone = $("#time").clone();       
    // Do something to change clone value
    $(clone).val('4:00 PM');
      $(".time_wrapper").append(clone);
});
```

```html
<div class="time_wrapper">
  <input type="text" value="3:00 PM" id="time"/>
</div>
<button id="add">Add More</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
$(document).on("click", "#add", function(){

    var clone = $("#time").clone();
    clone.removeAttr("id");
    clone.val("4:00 PM");
    // Do something to change clone value
      $(".time_wrapper").append(clone);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="time_wrapper">
  <input type="text" value="3:00 PM" id="time"/>
</div>
<button id="add">Add More</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is where you're going with this, but I would create a new element and append it, instead of trying to clone an existing one and update it's attributes.

```
$(".time_wrapper").append('<br/><input type="text" value="4:00 PM" />');
```

I removed the ID since you won't need it and added a line break to put your input on the next line of the page.